# Is it possible to read music meta data from a Meteor JS app?

Tags: audio, meteor, metadata

I understand it is possible to get a devive's native functions with Meteor JS (like camera, geolocation, accelerometer etc).

Is there some way of getting the meta data of music that is currently playing in a Meteor JS app? (or any other broadcasted data for that matter)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the HTML5 player (`<audio>` or `<video>` tags), there is an event you can track in Meteor:

```
Template.AudioPlayer.events({
  'loadedmetadata #audio_player':function (e) {
  //and you can access the metadata from e.target.whatever
  }
});
```